# VMware Horizon View Client - Failed to connect to the ViewConnection Server

Tags: 14.04

I've installed VMware Horizon View Client on 14.04 and now when I'm trying to connect to the server I'm getting the following error:

> Untrusted View Connection.  Failed to connect to the View Connection
>   Server.  The server provided an invalid certificate.  The certificate
>   authority is invalid or incorrect.

I changed the settings in preferences to not verify server identity, but then I get an error stating:

> smart card or certificate authentication is required

I'm able to use my CAC card to log into DoD sites in FireFox, so I don't think this has anything to do with my cac settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Under VMware, I selected

```
File > Preferences > Do not verify server identity certificates.
```

I then added the server and it worked perfectly.

Hope this helps!